# Java 3D - Build 3D models dynamically

Tags: java, 3d, translation, java-3d

im trying to build a 3D Model, by building dynamically 3D models and translate them to where i need them.

Im starting with a basic model, trying to to achieve what is on the picture bellow. I want to dynamically build two cylinders, and the X,Y,Z of the TOP of my cylinder will be the same X,Y,Z of the BOTTOM of the second Cylinder, like the picture bellow:
[image: What i want to achieve]

For now i have this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    int height = 10;
    int radius = 1;
    int angle = 0;

    BranchGroup objRoot = new BranchGroup();
    Cylinder cylinder;
    Vector3f last_coordinates = new Vector3f(0f,0f,0f);
    TransformGroup transf_group_cylinder = null;



    //---- Working ok -----/
    //build cylinder
    cylinder = new Cylinder(radius, height);
    transf_group_cylinder = createTransformGroup_Cylinder(new Vector3f(0f,0f,0f),angle);    
    transf_group_cylinder.addChild(cylinder);
    objRoot.addChild(transf_group_cylinder);

    last_coordinates = calculateLastPoint(height/2, angle);
    System.out.println(last_coordinates);
    //----------------------------//



    //build 2nd cylinder
    cylinder = new Cylinder(radius, height);
    transf_group_cylinder = createTransformGroup_Cylinder(last_coordinates, Math.PI/2); 
    transf_group_cylinder.addChild(cylinder);
    objRoot.addChild(transf_group_cylinder);

    OBJWriter objWriter = new OBJWriter("myObj.obj");
    objWriter.writeNode(objRoot);
    objWriter.close();

}

private static Vector3f calculateLastPoint(int height, int angle) {
    float x = (float) (height * Math.sin(angle));
    float y = (float) (height * Math.cos(angle));

    return new Vector3f(0, x, y);
}

private static TransformGroup createTransformGroup_Cylinder(
        Vector3f last_coordinates, double angle) {

    TransformGroup transf_group = new TransformGroup();

    //position the model
    Transform3D transform_origin = new Transform3D();
    transform_origin.setTranslation(new Vector3f(0, 0, 0)); 

    // set model in horizontal position
    Transform3D transf_horizontal = new Transform3D();
    transf_horizontal.rotZ(Math.PI / 2);
    transform_origin.mul(transf_horizontal);

    // rotate object
    Transform3D angleRotation = new Transform3D();
    angleRotation.rotX(angle);
    transform_origin.mul(angleRotation);

    Transform3D transform_xyz = new Transform3D();
    transform_xyz.setTranslation(last_coordinates);
    transform_origin.mul(transform_xyz); // set Transform for

    transf_group.setTransform(transform_origin);

    return transf_group;
}
```

With this code im achieving this:
[image]

My first cylinder is ok, but my 2nd cylinder is not placed in a proper place.
I can add **any value for the size and angle values**, so i need to calculate this two values in a  dynamically way.

Can someone help solving this translation problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: how about just altering the `last_coordinates` before creating cylinder 2. `last_coordinates.add(new Tuple3f(0, -height/2, 0));`

Comment: It wont solve my problem. If i have a different angle for the first cylinder, this will fail.

Comment: @user1907954: You have to apply all the transformations of the first cylinder to the points which you add to `last_coordinates` as well.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Could you exemplify how? i guess i didnt understand your point.

Comment: @user1907954: Currently, you use `Transform3D` to apply all kinds of 3D operations on the points to create the cylinder. You need to apply exactly the same operations to the end point (which should become the start point of the next cylinder) plus an additional translation of half the cylinder height to move it from the center to an end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step here is to give each cylinder a different color to allow you to see which one is which.

Next: When you create a cylinder, then it's centered at the origin. Since you want to chain them at the end point, you need to move them accordingly: First, you need to move the cylinder (or its transformation matrix) by -half its height to virtually move the "cylinder origin" to it's end.

The next step is that you need to apply the same transformation matrix to the end point (this time plus a full cylinder height), so it lines up with the actual end point.

That said, I would suggest you create a helper function that can create a cylinder between two points. This would allow you to say:

```
Point endPoint = cylinder(new Point(-1,.5,0), new Point(0,.5,0))
cylinder(endPoint, new Point(0,-.5,0))
...
```

or even create a helper function which accepts a list of points and creates all the cylinders between them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! For now i got the first and second steps (color and replace the origin in the bottom of my first cylinder) [progess here](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/716/qyy6.png) Now i dont know how to proceed. "The next step is that you need to apply the same transformation matrix to the end point (this time plus a full cylinder height), so it lines up with the actual end point." How can i accomplish this step? Thanks.

Comment: That means the end point is at (-height,0,0). So you need to create the next cylinder, rotate it accordingly, etc, but make sure that the start point stays at the origin. When you're done, you need to translate it to the end point at (-height,0,0). The new end point is now all the transformations of the second cylinder + 1 translation by (-height,0,0).

Comment: I undertand now, but still n the first cylinder -> what if my first cylinder is a specific angle? how can i rotate the first cylinder and find out the start point (x,0,0) for later on move it to origin(like i just did)?

Comment: You need to save the transformation matrix so you can apply it the end point. Then apply some more transformations (for the next cylinder) and apply it again.

Comment: The drawback of this approach is that calculation errors accumulate with this method. Which is why I suggest you find a way to create a cylinder between two arbitrary points. That way, you know exactly where the last cylinder ended (without keeping the transformation matrix around) and you can start the next one right away.